# setup dns on a ubuntu with public ip

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, dns

It's about 2 days that I want to setup DNS server on a server node on a cloud.
I'm following http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=236093 instructions but my dns is not accessible from outside.

dig samanamp.com --> works fine
ping samanamp.com --> host unreachable

My named.conf.local file:

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";
zone "samanamp.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/samanamp.com.db";
};

zone "89.94.146.115.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/rev.115.146.94.89.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

my samanamp.com.db file:

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.samanamp.com. root.samanamp.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.samanamp.com.
@       IN      A       115.146.94.89
@       IN      AAAA    ::1

;for domain
samanamp.com    IN      A       115.146.94.89
```

my rev.115.146.94.89.in-addr.arpa file:

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     samanamp.com. root.samanamp.com. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.
1.0.0   IN      PTR     ns.samanamp.com.
```

my ifconfig output(using dhcp):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:16:3e:c3:61:30
          inet addr:115.146.94.89  Bcast:115.146.95.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f816:3eff:fec3:6130/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:207659 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19419 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:24159414 (24.1 MB)  TX bytes:3616787 (3.6 MB)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...I want to setup a hosting for my domain samanamp.com.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to godaddy.com and register ns1.samanamp.com as 115.146.94.89 for the samanamp.com domain.

Once this happens, the internet will query your server for any name resolution for the domain.

You'll want to add NS records to your zone files to, to reflect the same setup.

Right now, while ns1.samanamp.com is the name server for the domain, the internet doesn't know how to resolve ns1.